# NullPointerException in Embedded Jetty when using JMX

Tags: jmx, embedded-jetty, prometheus

I get a NullPointerException every now and then in my Embedded Jetty application:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean.getAttribute(ObjectMBean.java:349)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1445)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.isShutdown(ContextHandler.java:682)
        ... 28 more
```

I have set up JMX like this:

```
Server server = new Server();
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(mBeanServer);
server.addBean(mbContainer);
```

This happens randomly (not always) at server startup and only if I have my Prometheous JMX Exporter running on the same machine, most likely connecting to the JMX server at a phase when Jetty is not quite ready to handle the connection.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: which version of jetty is this. ?

Answer (score 1):

The JMX exporter should be gracefully handling the error, so you shouldn't have to worry on the JMX side.

Looking at the jetty code, that's just a synchronised accessor so I don't see how you can get an NPE out of it. Presumably the object is null, so this is likely worth filing a bug against jetty.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out as much myself. I'm indeed planning to file a bug against Jetty. Seems like it's a Jetty bug and could be fixed easily.